# Titan DB bad index

Tags: scala, indexing, playframework, titan

I have this titan db schema:

```
val mgmt = getManagementSystem

val guid = mgmt.makePropertyKey("guid").dataType(classOf[String]).make()
mgmt.buildIndex("byGuid",classOf[Vertex]).addKey(guid).unique().buildCompositeIndex()
mgmt.commit()

mgmt.makePropertyKey("foo").dataType(classOf[String]).make()
mgmt.makePropertyKey("fo2").dataType(classOf[String]).make()
mgmt.makePropertyKey("about").dataType(classOf[String]).make()

/**
foo foo foo
*//

mgmt.commit()
```

when i Try do this:

```
db.V.has("guid", guid).next()
```

Then in Debug is this message:

```
[warn] c.t.t.g.t.StandardTitanTx - Query requires iterating over all vertices [()]. For better performance, use indexes
```

I used titan documentation and all is set like in documentation. I have no idea what is wrong, please help. Thx.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Titan Warning: Query requires iterating over all vertices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21725758/titan-warning-query-requires-iterating-over-all-vertices)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to wait for composite index to switch from `INSTALLED` to `ENABLED` state.

In order to do this, change your code to look like this

```
// Create an index
m = graph.openManagement()
m.buildIndex('names', Vertex.class).addKey(m.getPropertyKey('name')).buildCompositeIndex()
m.commit()
graph.tx().commit()

// Block until the SchemaStatus transitions from INSTALLED to REGISTERED
ManagementSystem.awaitGraphIndexStatus(graph, 'names').status(SchemaStatus.REGISTERED).call()

// Reindex using TitanManagement
m = graph.openManagement()
i = m.getGraphIndex('names')
m.updateIndex(i, SchemaAction.REINDEX)
m.commit()

// Enable the index
ManagementSystem.awaitGraphIndexStatus(graph, 'names').status(SchemaStatus.ENABLED).call()
```

For more information, have a look [here](http:////%20Create%20an%20index%20m%20=%20graph.openManagement()%20m.buildIndex('names',%20Vertex.class).addKey(m.getPropertyKey('name')).buildCompositeIndex()%20m.commit()%20graph.tx().commit()%20%20//%20Block%20until%20the%20SchemaStatus%20transitions%20from%20INSTALLED%20to%20REGISTERED%20ManagementSystem.awaitGraphIndexStatus(graph,%20'names').status(SchemaStatus.REGISTERED).call()%20%20//%20Reindex%20using%20TitanManagement%20m%20=%20graph.openManagement()%20i%20=%20m.getGraphIndex('names')%20m.updateIndex(i,%20SchemaAction.REINDEX)%20m.commit()%20%20//%20Enable%20the%20index%20ManagementSystem.awaitGraphIndexStatus(graph,%20'names').status(SchemaStatus.ENABLED).call())